# Can I do multiple MySQL work in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I wrote a code like this (I use MySQL, PDO, InnoDB, Laravel4, localhost & MAC) :

```
$all_queue = Queue1::all()->toArray(); //count about 10000
ob_end_clean();

foreach($all_queue as $key=>$value) {

    $priceCreate=array(...);
    Price::create($priceCreate);
    Queue1::where('id',$value['id'])->delete();
}
```

This worked for me (65mg ram usage), but when it was working, other parts of my program(such as other tables) didn't work. I can't open my database on mysql even. My program and my sql wait and when process is completed ,they work.

I don't know what am i supposed to do.
I think this is not for laravel and this is for my php or mysql configuration.

[this is my php.ini and mysql config](http://uploadboy.com/4631k46oz742.html)

Comment: There is an error in this code... $all_foreach() should be just foreach()

Answer (score 2):

I assume

```
$all_foreach($all_queue as $key=>$value) {
```

Is

```
foreach($all_queue as $key=>$value) {
```

And that you have no errors (you have set debug true in your app config).
Try to set no time limit for your script.

In your php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 3600  ;this is one hour, set to 0 to no limit
```

Or in code

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

And if it's a memory problem try to free memory and unset unused vars. I'ts a good practice in long scripts to free space.

```
    ...
}//end foreach loop
unset($all_queue); //no longer needed, so unset it to free memory
```

Comment: i think i cant explain my problem.

Comment: thanks, but my problem is , when that script is working , i cant access any part of my programm and my database. and i think its for php or mysql configuration but im not sure.

Comment: So your script is loading enormly long or isn't that the problem?